# how to Record Sound by selecting Input devices

Tags: vb.net, audio, audio-recording, input-devices, mcisendstring

I'm developing a program where it can record sound using many input devices (MIC). Therefore I can get inputs from many input devices at the same time. But when I'm trying it with "MCI strings" there's no place to specify the device ID. I takes only the default device ID here's my code using MCI Strings

```
Button1.Enabled = False
    Button2.Enabled = True
    mciSendString("open new type waveaudio alias recsound", "", 0, 0)
    mciSendString("record recsound", "", 0, 0)
    Label1.Text = "Recording"
```

is there's any other way to record sound? ex: Direct X ?

I'm using VB.Net. Your help is highly appreciated.

Thank You